# Chart display in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report on daily base date and I get a table where it display data of today when I run for today date.

Then I have a line chart which shows the graph of that date and the count of hit. Here, I need the graph to be shown for the whole month when I run the report not for only single date.

Please let me know the logic .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Dataset and define variables containing the range of data you need for whole month graph. Then select data using the variables.

Declaring variables:

```
declare @startOfMonth datetime2 = (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))  
declare @endOfMonth datetime2 = getdate()
```

Next, use this variables in your query:

```
select
/*
all data you need
*/
where date_of_data >= @startOfMonth and date_of_data <= @endOfMonth
```

Then use this Dataset in your new monthly graph.

Comment: hi thankyou for the reply .

what is that I need add in the place of date_of_data

Comment: If you display in your report data based on date I guess you have a column which you filter in "where" clause to display data of today. The "date_of_data" is the date column which you have in your data. You need to substitute it with your proper column name.